# Unable to find property "FrozenColumnCount" using Syncfusion with MAUI and .NET 7

Tags: xaml, maui, syncfusion, .net-7.0, sfdatagrid

I'm attempting to add the **FrozenColumnCount** ​property into my application. I add the appropriate line of code to my **xaml** ​file(seen in the final line of my **SfDataGrid** Tag)

```
<syncfusion:SfDataGrid

           ItemsSource="{Binding ProductItems}"

           ColumnWidthMode="Auto"

           GridLinesVisibility="Both"

           HeaderGridLinesVisibility="Both"

           AutoGenerateColumnsMode="None"

          FrozenColumnCount="1"

            >
//column data 
</syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
```

However when I build my app, I receive the following error

​***The property 'FrozenColumnCount' was not found in type 'SfDataGrid'***

I've only added that singular line to my xaml file to achieve the needed result. Is there anything else I need to add to get it to work ?

Comment: I see that property listed for their WinForms and WPF data grid but not for MAUI

Comment: @Jason Are you aware of anything similar that works with MAUI ?

Answer (score 0):

The syncfusion .net Maui DataGrid currently does not support frozen rows and columns. To learn about future plans for the .Net Maui DataGrid, please refer to the relevant documentation.

https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/datagrid/migration#upcoming-features